# How to show an alert if all checkboxes aren't checked?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox, alert

I want alert if check-box is **not** checked (- this is working )

and

Alert if **ALL** check-box is **not** checked  ( need help in this )

*CheckBox :*

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="data" name="data[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" id="data" name="data[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="3" id="data" name="data[]">
```

*Button :*

```
<input name=\"submitclose\" type=\"submit\"  value=\"Close\" id=\"submitclose\">
```

*Below is my Jquery :*

```
echo "<script>
jQuery(function($)  {
$(\"input[id='submitclose']\").click(function() {  

                var count_checked = $(\"[id='data']:checked\").length; 
                if (count_checked == 0)  {
                        alert(\"Please select a Packet(s) to Close.\");
                        return false;
                } else{     
                        return confirm(\"Are you sure you want to Close these Packet?\");
                }  
        });
}); 
</script>";
```

Comment: id should be unique...! :/

Comment: Probably need to use a loop to test for all and make your `id`'s unique so you can do so.

Comment: hey, above checkbox are coming in php loop itself .. i means Value are in loop ...

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pFFGR/1/

Comment: or http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/pFFGR/2/

Comment: @Arun : thanks +1 for 2 jsfiddle , dude one doubt why u have used  
 " var $checks ", it should be " var checks " , because when i used $checks its showed me error but  with " var checks " its working.

Comment: sorry, it might be because `$` has a special meaning in PHP...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try,

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" id="data1" name="data[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" id="data2" name="data[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="3" id="data3" name="data[]">
```

JS:

```
var allCheckBox = $("[id^='data']")
var count_checked = allCheckBox.filter(":checked").length; 
if (count_checked == 0)  {
    alert("All check boxes are not checked");
} else if(count_checked != allCheckBox.length) {
    alert("some of the check boxs are not checked");
} else{     
    return confirm("Are you sure you want to Close these Packet?");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(\"input[id='submitclose']\").click(function(){
    var count = 0;
    $('input#data').each(function(){   
    if ($(this).attr('checked') == true){
    count++  //if a checkbox is checked the variable count will be greater then 0.
    }
})
    if (count == 0){      //nothing is checked.
    alert("Please check at least one of the checkboxes");
}else{       //something is checked.
    //code to execute.
}

})
```